# Is there any way of manually arranging list item with CSS/jQuery (sorting them just once, not dragging them around)?

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, sorting

I have a navigation menu with 12 items:

(firebug inspector with one list item expanded)

```
<ul id="forums">
<li>
<a rel="bookmark" title="Permalink to Business" href="http://www.taiwantalk.org/forum/business/">Business</a>
</li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
<li>
</ul>
```

I would like to sort them manually with CSS/jQuery (sorting them just once, not dragging them around).

Any suggestions?

**EDIT:**

I'm using Wordpress, and I can't find the way of sorting 'custom post types' manually.

Comment: how would you like to sort them?

Comment: Your question is still a bit vague, you say you want to sort them once but then why don't you do this within the HTML?

Comment: If you only want to sort the list once, wouldn't it be easier to populate the list in the correct (sorted) order?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this? (I used it myself)
http://wil-linssen.com/entry/extending-the-jquery-sortable-with-ajax-mysql/

Answer (score 1):

You might want to look into jQuery UI ... http://jqueryui.com/demos/ ... which has draggable/sortable/etc. features that are fairly easy to implement. There are several jQuery plugins that do the same thing without jQuery UI.

A non-jQuery option is something like http://tool-man.org/examples/sorting.html

Comment: Sorry, I didn't explain myself clear. I mean just sorting them once. I don't want to be able to drag them around.